# Handle http error using switchMap and return empty Observable

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, angular-reactive-forms

Just want to ask how to properly handle this scenario.
I have a form which built using reactive form. This form loads the details of the selected user that I have selected from the list (users) to edit the details.

Displaying the data in the form is working as expected. Below is my code implementation.

In my service, I have this code to pull a single record from an API.

**SERVICE**

```
    private selectedUserIdSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number | null>(null);
    selectedUserIdAction$ = this.selectedUserIdSubject.asObservable();

    user$ = this.selectedUserIdAction$
        .pipe(
            switchMap(id => this.httpClient.get<IUserInfo>(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}/users/{id}`)
            ),
        );
```

**NOTE:** When calling the API with ID is not exist, it returns an `503 Service Unavailable` error.

**COMPONENT**

```
    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
          this.selectedUserId = +params['id'];

          this.userService.onSelectedUserId(this.selectedUserId);
        })

        this.initUserForm();
    }

    selectedUser$ = this.userService.user$
        .pipe(
            tap(data => {

              if (data !== null) {
                this.loadUserDetails(data);
              }
            })
    );
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-container mat-elevation-z8" *ngIf="selectedUser$ | async as user">
    <form class="form-container" [formGroup]="userForm">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Firstname*" formControlName="FirstName">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Lastname*" formControlName="LastName">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Address*" formControlName="Address">
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now, I decided to use the same form for creating a new record. My approach would be, when I clicked the "**NEW BUTTON**", I should be redirected to  form (Edit) with a parameter of `-1` to indicate that I'll be creating a new record and not loading the details with `-1` ID.

My problem now is that, since I'm using a reactive programming approach, every time my component loads, the `selectedUser$` observable always trigger and my service trigger an http request to the API and trying to find a user detail with `-1` ID.

I'm thinking in my service, when the ID is `-1`, I will return an empty `Observable` with `IUserInfo` type. But seems not working and the error still persist as stated in the above error.

```
    user$ = this.selectedUserIdAction$
        .pipe(
            switchMap(id => {
                if (id !== -1) {
                    this.httpClient.get<IUserInfo>(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}/users/{id}`
                } else {
                    return new Observable<IUserInfo>();
                }
            })
            ),
        );
```

What I want is that, when I have a `-1` parameter, It should load and initialize the form for creating a new record.

TIA!

Comment: return new Observable<IUserInfo>(); is invalid, as ```Obserbable```'s constructor is accepts an observer as param. – Rafi Henig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option is to complete an observable sequence, i.e.

```
.pipe(
    switchMap(_ => this.httpClient.get<IUserInfo>(`/users/{id}`))
    catchError(userInfo => {
        // Do something with error, like log, etc
        return empty()
    })
)
```

in this case, if previous observable (httpClient) throws an error, it will be completed, ie subscription section will not be reached... Ideal case in your case

Second option is to return predictable results, for example if endpoint returns an array, you can return an observable of empty array

```
.pipe(
    switchMap(_ => this.httpClient.get<IUserInfo>(`/users/{id}`))
    catchError(userInfo => {
        // Do something with error, like log, etc
        return of({})
    })
)
```

Third option is to property handle error in subscriber, but it will not be your case as long as you use async pipe

```
.pipe(
    switchMap(_ => this.httpClient.get<IUserInfo>(`/users/{id}`))
)
.subscribe(res => {}, err => {
    // return predictable results here
})
```

Although I'd recommend to achieve this with ErrorHandler Interceptor and additional checks. Error handler interceptor will catch all server error and handle error accordingly.. In your case you also can prepend api origin via interceptor, so you don't have to add it manually to each service

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // Appending environment.origin only if url is not starts with protocol
        if (!req.url.match(new RegExp('^https?://'))) {
            req = req.clone({
                url: environment.origin + req.url
            });
        }

        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            catchError(error => {
                if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    // Do something with an error here
                }
                return throwError(error);
            })
        );
    }
}

.pipe(
    switchMap(_ => this.httpClient.get<UserInfo>(`/users/{id}`)),
    map(userInfo => !userInfo || typeof userInfo !== 'object' ? {}  : userInfo),
    catchError(err => empty())
)
```

Also, get through [TypeScript Coding Guidelines](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines) . IUserInfo is not complied with it...

Comment: Thanks Timothy for your suggestion, I'll try this. And thank you for giving the coding guideline. Cheers!

Comment: Second option works for me. Many thanks for the suggestions Timothy. Last thing, is there any way to get rid on the error not to display in the browser console since my intention is not to search the `-1` id rather than I'm doing a new record? Thanks!

Comment: No problem. There is https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler. You will need to intercept it and write your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Returning `new Observable<IUserInfo>()` is invalid, as Obserbable's constructor accepts an observer. as follows:

```
switchMap(id => {
     if (id !== -1) this.httpClient.get<IUserInfo>(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}/users/{id}`
     else return new Observable<IUserInfo>(x => x.next(null));     
})
```

How about subsribing to `selectedUser$`  within `ngOnInt` and unless id is bigger than -1 `ngOnInt` will be returned.

```js
selectedUser$;

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.selectedUserId = +params['id'];
    if (this.selectedUserId > -1) return this.initUserForm();

    this.userService.onSelectedUserId(this.selectedUserId);
    this.selectedUser$ = this.userService.user$
      .pipe(
        tap(data => {
          if (data !== null) this.loadUserDetails(data);
          this.initUserForm();
        })
      );
  })
}
```

If you prefer `selectedUser$` to hold a user instance:

```js
if (this.selectedUserId > -1) {
   this.selectedUser = of(new IUserInfo())
   return this.initUserForm();
}
```

**UserInfo.ts**

```js
export default class UserInfo implements IUserInfo{
    constructor(
        public email: string = "",
        public username: string = ""
    ) {}
}
```

Comment: thanks Rafi, just tried what you have shared but tweak a little in your code. The next issue is that, my form will not be visible since it using an async pipe `*ngIf="selectedUser$ | async as user"`

Comment: Since you don't have any data when creating a new user what 'truthy' value do you expect of ```selectedUser$``` to hold?

Comment: Since the first implementation of this form is for edit detail purposes only, `selectedUser$` expect a value from API. That's my challenge now how do I reuse this form for new record and I'm not sure what should be the value of `selectedUser$`